# How to parse out all links from source with Jericho in Java while filtering out or ignoring elements with a specific id?

Tags: java, jericho-html-parser

I am using the Jericho java client library to parse out all href links. What I want to do is filter out or skip all links from the source that contain a specific id. I have tried several things, and my solution is not pretty but basically I can accomplish this by checking on something like this:

```
for(Element element : elements) {
  if (element.getAllStartTags().toString().contains("skip_me")) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But I prefer a cleaner solution. Let's assume this is the source:

```
<td>
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="skip_me" />
</td>
<td>
 <a href="http://www.google.com" />
</td>
```

Just a small snippet, but what I want this to return me in the end is just "www.google.com". I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
for( Element element : elements )
{
    if( element.getStartTag().getName() == HTMLElementName.A ) // Select only 'a'-tags
    {
        final String id = element.getAttributeValue("id"); // Get Attribute 'id'

        if( id == null || !id.equals("skip_me") ) // Process element if it has a.) no id (null) or b.) the id is not 'skip_me'
        {
            System.out.println(element); // Process Element
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
*(using your html)*

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Another solution:       

List<Element> elements = source.getAllElements("a");        
for(Element element : elements )
     {
      final String id = element.getAttributeValue("id");
      if(id == null || !id.equals("skip_me")) 
         {
          System.out.println(element.toString());    
         }
     }
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" />
```